# How to convert a loop from perl to powershell?

Tags: perl, powershell, powershell-2.0

I was trying to convert a perl script to powershell script.

I don't know how to convert the following looping to powershell.

```
my %ba;
while ( my ( $before, $afters_aref ) = each %deps ) {
  for my $after ( @{ $afters_aref } ) {
        $ba{$before}{$after} = 1 if $before ne $after;
        $ba{$after} ||= {};
    }
}
```

Please help me to convert it.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really tested this, but I think this will work.

```
$ba = @{}
foreach ( $dep in $deps.GetEnumerator()) { 
    foreach ( $after in $dep.Value ) { 
        if ( $dep.Key -ne $after ) {
           if ( -not $ba.ContainsKey( $dep.Key )) { 
               $ba[ $dep.Key ] = @{ $after=1 };
           }
           else {
               $ba[ $dep.Key ].$after = 1;
           }
        }
        if ( -not $ba.ContainsKey( $after )) { 
            $ba[ $after ] = @{}
        }
    }
}
```

I would have liked to do it in a pipeline, but I'm still learning all the quirks involved.

---

In order to do the autovivification that Perl does, I whipped up this other version. You should note that I *can't* `add-member` when `$ba` is declared the way it is above.

```
$ba = new-object System.Collections.Hashtable;
$ba | add-member ScriptMethod deepset {
    $p = $args;
    if ( $p[0] -is [System.Array] ) {
        $p = $p[0];
    }
    $p = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$p;
    $last = $p.count - 1;
    $val = $p[ $last ];
    $p.RemoveAt( $last-- );
    $key = $p[ $last ];
    $p.RemoveAt( $last-- );
    $lvl = $this;
    foreach ( $k in $p ) {
        if ( $lvl.containsKey( $k )) {
           $old = $lvl.$k;
           if ( $old -isnot [System.Collections.Hashtable] ) {
               $lvl.$k = @{ '.' = $old };
           }
        }
        else {
            $lvl.$k = @{};
        }
        $lvl = $lvl.$k;
    }
    $lvl.$key = $val;
    return;
}

# allowing the loop to be a bit shorter. 

foreach ( $dep in $deps.GetEnumerator()) { 
    foreach ( $after in $dep.Value ) { 
        if ( $dep.Key -ne $after ) {
           $ba.deepset( $dep.Key, $after, $true );
        }
        if ( -not $ba.ContainsKey( $after )) { 
            $ba[ $after ] = @{}
        }
    }
}
```